# Assigning two variables from popping a stack

Tags: java

So I have a stack of numbers that I gave using a helper stack and a parser. Essentially what I'm doing is creating a calculator. Eclipse is giving my errors on my code and I can't seem to figure out what's the issue behind it. When I need to evaluate an expression, I pop once from a char stack which defines which expression I'm using, and then pop the number stack twice using the following code.

```
    char operator = operatorStack.pop();
    double b = numberStack.pop();
    double a = numberStack.pop();
```

Then, using these three variables I assign them into a method I have that evaluates the expression.

```
    double eval = evaluateOperator(a, operator, b);
```

Afterwords I push the variable eval back into the number list and cycle through. But that's not the issue. My main question is, is this the correct way to assign variables from a stack using the pop method?

Comment: How are your stacks defined and what is the compilation error you actually get?

Comment: It is if the stack has doubles and they're in the right order. How *else* would you do it? E.g., what makes you wonder if it's correct? Is it working?

Comment: Most probably you defined stack as `Stack<Object>` or even as untyped `Stack`. `pop()` in either case returns `Object`, so you need to cast it to `Double` and `Char` accordingly before assigning to variables. Also please note, that `Stack` is deprecated in Java, you should use any [`Dequeue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) implementations instead (for example, `LinkedList`).

Comment: The actual issue is the fact that it's giving me an empty stack exception. Which obviously results in java.util.Stack.peek(Unknown Source) and java.util.Stack.pop(Unknown Source). I think it has to do with the fact that the stack isn't being placed inside and thus, it's peeking/popping and empty stack. I'll figure it out, thanks for the help!